# How to use put in bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

I don't know how to use PUT in bottle, the code is below:

```
    @put('/ws/users/contacts/:uid/:cid')
    def modifyContact(uid,cid):
        contact = request.json
        print contact
```

but when i run the app, and visit the /ws/users/contacts/1/2, 
the app can't step into the route and call on the modifyContact method.

when the code like this:

```
    @put('/ws/users/contacts/:uid')
    def modifyContact(uid):
        contact = request.json
        print contact
```

visit the /ws/users/contacts/1, 
everything will be ok and i can get contact in console.

Can you tell me why? There is something wrong with the parameter?

Comment: could you show more of what your code looks like?  just the import statements, a single route, and what you're doing to run the server should be enough to see what's going on.

Comment: What error message, or unexpected result, do you get?

Comment: I think i resolved the problem. Maybe something wrong with other programs, and i just alterd some places. Thank you very much!